# Is this a Martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Is there any way to decide whether for $X_n$, $Y_n$ martingales for the same filtration,

$$Z_n = (X_n+Y_n)1_{Y_n>0} + X_n1_{Y_n\leq0}$$

is a martingale, sub-martingale or super-martingale?

Obviously, $Z_n$ has finite expectation and is measurable w.r.t the given filtration, however, I cannot seem to find a way to proof any of the martingale properties.

Comment: May be yes, may be no... what are your thoughts, what have you tried, and if you tried something, where are you stuck ?

Comment: Well, it is quite clear that $E[Z_n|F_{n-1}] = E[X_n|F_{n-1}] + E[Y_n1_{Y_{n}>0}|F_{n-1}]$. However, I would have to proof that this second term is somehow $\geq$, $=$ or $\leq$ then $Y_{n-1}1_{Y_{n-1}>0}$ for all $n$. This is really where I am stuck, as I cannot see any way to get such a statement with the given assumptions.

Comment: Have you tried an example?  For instance, what if $Y$ is a simple random walk?

Comment: No, I don't have any further assumption on the martingales.

Comment: @BrianMoehring As the SRW takes values in $\mathbb{Z}$, $Z_n$ is a super-martingale.

Answer (score 1):

We may write $Z_n = X_n + \max(0,Y_n)$, and since both the sum and the maximum of two submartingales is a submartingale, $Z_n$ is a submartingale.

On the other hand, if we set $X_n=0$ and let $Y_n$ be a symmetric, simple random walk starting at $Y_0=0\in \mathbb{Z}$, then we can check directly that $E[Z_1] > 0 = E[Z_0]$.
Therefore $Z_n$ is neither a supermartingale nor a martingale.

Comment: And if $(Y_n)$ is non-negative, then $(Z_n)$ is even a martingale.